# What's that "Classes-1.moved-aside" directory in my Classes directory?

Tags: iphone, xcode

In the XCode project folder (the real one on my hard drive) there's a "Classes-1.moved-aside" folder inside the "Classes" folder. It contains a few files which are also in the "Classes" folder. What's the point of that "Classes-1.moved-aside" folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are for classes that you deprecated.
One way you can get them is if you create a new class with the same name of another class, xcode will move the old class into a moved aside folder.